Why hash find method behaves differently with length statement and "if 0 then set" statement
I have following exemplary piece of code:
data hh;
keyx=1; xx=21;output;
keyx=3; xx=23;output;
keyx=4; xx=24;output;
keyx=5; xx=25;output;
run;

data tbl;
keyx=1;output;
keyx=2;output;
keyx=4;output;
keyx=5;output;
keyx=1;output;
keyx=6;output;
run;

data tbl_h_bezset;
length xx 8.;
if _N_=1 then do;
/*if 0 then set hh;*/
      declare hash hh(dataset:'hh');
      hh.definekey('keyx');
      hh.definedata('xx');
      hh.definedone();
end;
set tbl;
rc=hh.find();
run;


data tbl_h_set;
/*length xx 8.;*/
if _N_=1 then do;
if 0 then set hh;
      declare hash hh(dataset:'hh');
      hh.definekey('keyx');
      hh.definedata('xx');
      hh.definedone();
end;
set tbl;
rc=hh.find();
run;

I find it difficult to understand the difference in result. tbl_h_bezset uses length statement to include xx in PDV. Resulting dataset has correct matches from find() method and missing values where there was no match. However, if I use "if 0 then set" in order to include xx in PDV (instead of length statement) i get wrong matches in xx variable instead of missing values. It looks like sas gets the xx value from the previous row, the last one where the mach has been found. I guess i somehow get why tbl_h_set outputs what it outputs. "If 0 then set" creates variables in PDV vector. In row X match has been found. In row X+1 there was no match, but since tbl dataset doesnt involve xx variable, PDV vector uses the value from previous row, that has not been cleared in the PDV. Am I right? And, what's more important, why tbl_h_bezset, that uses LENGTH statement instead, results in a correct match everytime.
I hope with your help I'll get some clarification.
I have tried searching throught the internet and stackoverflo forum already. I have tested multiple methods and I cannot understend the difference in mechanics.

Why not just use the return code from the find() method to decide when the variables need to be cleared?

Good question. And very important to understand when working with hash objects.
The key is the difference in when the SAS Data Step automatically sets variables to missing. You can read the documentation in When Variable Values Are Automatically Set to Missing by SAS. Especially the last part When Reading a SAS Data Set is important.
The short of the long is that the Set Statement sets variable values to missing only before the first iteration of the DATA step (not considering the case of By Statement). This is usually sufficient in the usual case, the Set Statement reads another value in the next iteration and so on.
In the case of if 0 then set, it is up to you to ensure that the values are missing if there is no match in the hash object. Therefore, you will often see the if 0 then set statement followed by a Call Missing Statement.
data tbl_h_set;
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash hh(dataset:'hh');
      hh.definekey('keyx');
      hh.definedata('xx');
      hh.definedone();
   end;

   set tbl;

   if 0 then set hh;
   call missing(xx);

   rc=hh.find();
run;

On the other hand, when using the Length Statement, the variable value is set to missing automatically at the beginning of each Data Step iteration.
data tbl_h_set;
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash hh(dataset:'hh');
      hh.definekey('keyx');
      hh.definedata('xx');
      hh.definedone();
   end;

   set tbl;

   length xx 8.;

   rc=hh.find();
run;

There are pros and cons for both methods. The major pro for the if 0 then set method is that you need not know in advance the length of the variables you create in the PDV. This is automatically inherited.

To avoid the issue of retained values, I almost explicitly use length statements if I have a hash table with variables not in the set tables. I wrote a macro that can generate me the length statements of a table in the correct variable order and saves it into a macro variable. I can then add the macro variable in the program to get me all the variables I need in their correct length and order.

That answear is great and i highly appreciate it, thank you a lot.

@StuSztukowski would you mind sharing that macro program? I mean, it looks like I would be easily capable of programming it myself, however, if you do not mind sharing I would be grateful as it would be a little time saver.

https://github.com/stu-code/sas/blob/master/utility-macros/getattribs.sas

Variables that are defined NEW by a data step are not retained unless you explicitly add a RETAIN statement (or implicitly add it by using them as the target in a SUM statement).
But variables that are sourced from datasets (ie included in SET, MERGE or UPDATE statements) are RETAINED.  That is why a 1 to MANY merge is able to work.
Note that a dataset accessed via the DATASET: option of the DECLARE HASH statement are not even seen by the data step compiler. Notice how the name of the dataset is enclosed in quotes there.  To the data step compiler that is just another string.  That is why you will need to add code like the LENGTH or SET statement that will let the data step compiler know what type and length the variables should have. Otherwise the normal rules the data step compiler uses when having to guess what type of variable was intended will apply.
